# How do I determine the name of a table style in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

Running Word 2016. I have a Word document that already contains a table of a certain style. I've gone through the list of table styles, but I can't find this style in the list.

I was under the impression that any style that is used in a document gets saved in the list of styles.

I want to use this style in another document I'm generating via python-docx (or indeed, in any other document) but I don't know how to identify the name of the table style.

I have tried right clicking on the table and going to "table properties", but that just lets you configure how the table looks. I can't seem to find a way to tell me what the name of the table style is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!